# input.nextLine() gets skipped

Tags: java, input, printing

this is probably pretty simple, but I can't figure it out.  I just have a simple series of keyboard inputs with a prompt string in front of them, and for some reason, it just decides to skip one.  Code:

```
            System.out.println("Enter student ID");
            int i = input.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Enter Last Name");
            String l = input.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter First Name");
            String f = input.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter major");
            String m = input.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter GPA");
            Double g = input.nextDouble();

            System.out.println("Inserted student record");
            StudentBST.insert(i, l, f, m, g);
```

When I run it though, it just straight up skips over the Last Name entry, and moves on to First Name.  The run output looks like this.

```
Enter student ID
3
Enter Last Name
Enter First Name
ellen
Enter major
art
Enter GPA
3.4
```

Right there, just skips entering Last Name.  Any ideas as to why?

Comment: There is still a new line character in the stream after `input.nextInt`, you need to use `input.nextLine()` to clear it BEFORE you ask the next prompt.  Same goes for all the other `.nextXxx` methods...other than `nextLine`...

Comment: This seems to happen all the time.